# outer Join in linq with lambda expression

Tags: c#, sql, linq, lambda

I have 2 tables ProfileType(profilename), Role(roldId,minSecurityLevel) and many to many relationship between this as roleProfiles(roleid,profilename,securityLevel)

I want to select all profileTypes and security levels for that profileType to particular role.

If roleProfile does not contain the entry for profiletype it will show null.

Can anyone help me for linq query using only lambda expression?

I am using repository Pattern

```
        var roleprofiles =  Repository.Query<Model.RoleProfile>()
            .Select(
                r =>
                new RoleProfileModel
                {
                    SecurityLevel = r.SecurityLevel,
                    ProfileCode = r.ProfileType.Code
                })
            .ToArray();
```

I want the result for left join on profileTypes

Comment: Can you post some code for your Role / ProfileType model classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var details= (from p in repository.Query<Model.ProfileType>()
             join r in repository.Query<Model.RoleProfile>() on p.Id equals r.ProfileTypeId into g
             from x in g.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select new RoleProfileModel{
                    ProfileType=p.Name,
                    SecurityLevel=x==null?string.Empty:x.SecurityLevel,
                    ProfileCode=x==null?string.Empty:x.Code,
}).ToArray();
```

hope it will help you

Comment: I know this is old, but while searching for the same thing I found this. However, from my understanding, this is not lambda expression.

Answer (score 4):

lambda version

```
  var roleprofiles =  Repository.Query<Model.RoleProfile>()
           .GroupJoin(Repository.Query<Model.ProfileType>(),
                      rp=>rp.Id, pt=>pt.TheRPId, // the the fields the tables are joined on  
            (rp,pt)   =>  new RoleProfileModel
            {
                SecurityLevel = rp.SecurityLevel,
                ProfileCode = rp.ProfileType.Code,
                XYZ         = pt.somethingFromProfType 
            })
        .ToList();   // to array ??? to List is better
```